# Haskell: trying to understand the type of fmap (+) (1)

Tags: haskell

i am trying to understand why there is no type error for `fmap (+) (1)`

I do understand the following sequence:

```
Prelude> :t  fmap 
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude> :t  (+)  
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a                          # like a-> b with b = a -> a
Prelude> :t  fmap (+)
fmap (+) :: (Functor f, Num a) => f a -> f (a -> a)
Prelude> :t  fmap (+) (Just 1)                       
fmap (+) (Just 1) :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)         # f=Maybe is implied by the Just constructor
Prelude>
```

I expected a type error for `fmap (+) (1)` since there is no functor implied for (1), instead i get:

```
Prelude> :t (1)
(1) :: Num p => p
Prelude> :t  (+)  
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a                          
Prelude> :t  fmap (+)
fmap (+) :: (Functor f, Num a) => f a -> f (a -> a)
Prelude> :t  fmap (+) (1)
fmap (+) (1) :: (Functor f, Num a, Num (f a)) => f (a -> a)  ## why ??
Prelude>
```

why is this ?

Similarly, i don't understand the type of `fmap (+) id`:

```
Prelude> :t  fmap (+)   
fmap (+) :: (Functor f, Num a) => f a -> f (a -> a)
Prelude> :t  id      
id :: a -> a
Prelude> :t  fmap (+) id
fmap (+) id :: Num a => a -> a -> a       ## why no error ?
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numerical literals can fit *any* type, provided it is a numeric type (in class `Num`).

GHC works under an open-world assumption, where even if a type does not belong to an instance right now, it might be in the future. This is because it is possible to write a new module and declare an instance there, and we want separate compilation.

For numeric types, this means that even if a type is not numeric right now, it might still be later on.

Suppose we write `reverse 1`. It looks wrong, since `reverse` expects a list, and `1` is not a list. Or is it? Even if `[a]` is not numeric now, it might be in the future, hence the type of `reverse 1` is `Num [a] => [a]`, and not a type error. Of course, under normal circumstances we won't have a `Num [a]` instance, but GHC can not assume that.

In your specific example, `fmap` wants an `f a` and you pass `(1)`, which is the same as `1`. Here, this numeric literal gets instantiated as `Num (f a) => f a`, so that type checking works.

```
fmap (+) (1) :: (Functor f, Num a, Num (f a)) => f (a -> a)
```

The above constraint `Num (f a)` is required to allow `1` to be interpreted in the type `f a`. Then `f` must be a functor because `fmap` requires it, and we must have `Num a` since `(+)` requires its argument to be numeric (the argument of `(+)` has type `a` and its result has type `a -> a`, where `a` must be numeric). We get `f (a -> a)` as a result again because of the return type of `(+)`.

---

About `fmap (+) id`, this is simpler. Here `id :: (->) a a`, that is `id :: f a` where `f = (->) a`, which happens to be a functor. For this functor we have that `fmap = (.)`, the functional composition operator. Hence, `fmap (+) id` means `(.) (+) id`, or `(+) . id` which is simply `(+)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple consequence of the fact that number literals such as `1` are polymorphic - their type is `(Num a) => a`. In addition, there is no fixed list of numeric types, as Haskell allows you to make your own instances for any class - including `Num` - anywhere.

As a result, in applying this:

```
Prelude> :t  fmap (+)
fmap (+) :: (Functor f, Num a) => f a -> f (a -> a)
```

to the literal `1`, the type checker only needs to check if it's possible to unify the type of `1` with the input type `f a`. Given the polymorphic type of `1` as above, this is clearly possible provided there is an instance of `Num` available for `f a` - as then `f a` is a valid type for `1`. And this explains the final type.

As for `fmap (+) id`, this is rather different. Here GHC needs to unify `f a` (for a functor `f` and numeric `a`) with `a -> a`, which results in the only possible choice for `f`, the "function functor" `((->) a)` (where `fmap` is just composition). That is `f b` here means `a -> b`, and so `f (a -> a)` is `a -> a -> a`.